# How would I go about making a recurrence relation for an algorithm like this?

Tags: java, relation, recurrence

I need to find the recurrence relation for the number of multiplications performed for this algorithm that finds base^n, but I don't really know how to go about doing it because of the IF at the bottom.

```
public int reduceAndConquer(int base, int n){
 if(n == 1) return base;
 if(n == 2) return base*base;
 else{
   int total = reduceAndConquer(base, n/2);
   if(n%2 == 0) return total*total;
   return total*total*base;
 } 
}
```

Since it's either 1 or 2 multiplications depending on whether it's even or odd, I'm not sure how to work this into a relation. Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do even/odd branches in a recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n/2)+1          for n even
T(n) = T(floor(n/2))+2   for n odd
```

or another way of expressing the same:

```
T(2k) = T(k)+1
T(2k+1) = T(k)+2
```

Or if you really want to have one formula:

```
T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + 1 + n%2
```

where n%2 is of course shorthand for n-(2*floor(n/2))